# Extracting new columns with counts out of pandas data frame groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am dealing with a pandas dataframe like this one:

```
     Day  Hour         Prio  Value
0      1     6     Critical      1
1      1    16     Critical      1
2      1    17      Content      1
3      1    17          Low      1
6      1    19     Critical      1
7      1    20         High      1
8      2    10         High      1
9      2    10          Low      2
```

And now I want want to group by Day and Hour while generating new columns representing the count of each value in the column `Prio`, which currently is present in the column `value`. So I want to achieve this structure:

```
     Day  Hour  Critical  Content  Low  High
0      1     6         1        0    0     0
1      1    16         1        0    0     0
2      1    17         0        1    1     0
6      1    19         1        0    0     0
7      1    20         0        0    0     1
8      2    10         0        0    2     1
```

I tried different things now, but have not been rather successful. I am targeting at merging this data frame with another one containing other columns by Day and Hour in order to further aggregate them. Especially I need the percentage shares per day/hour among the priorities (at least one non-zero value is always present).

In a past solution I was iterating over each row to extract the single values, but this has been rather slow. I want to keep it as efficient as possible as the data should update live within a bokeh server app. Maybe there is a solution without using `itertuples` or something similar? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df.groupby(['Day','Hour','Prio']).sum().unstack().fillna(0).astype(int)
#           Value                  
#Prio     Content Critical High Low
#Day Hour                          
#1   6          0        1    0   0
#    16         0        1    0   0
#    17         1        0    0   1
#    19         0        1    0   0
#    20         0        0    1   0
#2   10         0        0    1   2
```

You can further reset index, if you want.

Comment: `unstack` was the missing link here and I do not know, how I could live without it. Your solution as well as `pivot_table` are working perfectly fine and with great performance compared to my humble prior approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Or you can try

```
pd.pivot_table(df,values='Value',index=['Day','Hour'],columns=['Prio'],aggfunc='sum')\
     .fillna(0).astype(int)


Out[22]: 
Prio      Content  Critical  High  Low
Day Hour                              
1   6           0         1     0    0
    16          0         1     0    0
    17          1         0     0    1
    19          0         1     0    0
    20          0         0     1    0
2   10          0         0     1    2
```

Comment: Consider converting the results to `int`, as they are supposed to represent counts.

Comment: I tried this solution but upon time testing, it gave 14.6 ms per loop as against 5.84 ms per loop with @DYZ's solution

Comment: Thank you for the `pivot_table` function, which shows a similarly great performance as the `unstack` approach and both exactly are, what I needed. As I want to calculate relative values, I do not need to convert them to integers and left that away.

Answer (score 1):

Let's use `set_index`, `unstack`, `reset_index`, and `rename_axis`:

```
df.set_index(['Day','Hour','Prio'])['Value']\
  .unstack().fillna(0)\
  .astype(int).reset_index()\
  .rename_axis(None,1)
```

Output:

```
   Day  Hour  Content  Critical  High  Low
0    1     6        0         1     0    0
1    1    16        0         1     0    0
2    1    17        1         0     0    1
3    1    19        0         1     0    0
4    1    20        0         0     1    0
5    2    10        0         0     1    2
```